# Python: is there a way to define a global scale of colors and plot colored lines using this custom scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been reading about multiple lines plotting and [multicolored lines](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py), but every time I read a post about it people use continuous set of data, like some trigonometrical function:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 3 * np.pi, 500)
y = np.sin(x)
```

So, here is my problem: I'm making a plotting script for 1D finite element problems [like the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GMxZ.png). I'm plotting the elements as individual lines with the X and Y coordinates array, and I would like to color the lines based on a third array like the axial stress or temperature, or any other

The problem is when I try to follow the examples I've found, every line has local color distribution, instead of a global distribution. I'm thinking about defining a global color scale based on the maximum and mininum values of the third array, let's say temperature, and passing the coordinates of each element + the current average temperature may do the job, but I don't know if something alike is possible

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map values to a particular colormap, and plot each element as a single line with a particular color, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import numpy as np

# roto-translation matrix
T = lambda t, u, v: np.array([[np.cos(t), -np.sin(t), u], [np.sin(t), np.cos(t), 0], [0, 0, 1]])
# coordinates of a triangle
triangle = np.array([[-0.5, -0.5, 1], [0.5, -0.5, 1], [-0.5, 0.5, 1], [-0.5, -0.5, 1]]).T

n_elements = 10
values = np.linspace(-5, 5, n_elements)
# create a normalizer
norm = Normalize(vmin=values.min(), vmax=values.max())
# normalize values
norm_values = norm(values)
# choose a colormap
cmap = cm.magma
# create colors
colors = cmap(norm_values)

# map values to a colorbar
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
mappable.set_array(values)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_aspect("equal")

for i in range(n_elements):
    tr = np.matmul(T(i * np.pi, int(i / 2), 0), triangle)
    ax.plot(tr[0, :], tr[1, :], color=colors[i])

cb = f.colorbar(mappable)
cb.set_label("Value")
```

[image]